# Complex Interpretations of Waves

Tags: waves, complex-numbers

Many wave equations and graphs I have seen include both an imaginary part and a real part and I was wondering what the meaning and implications of these different parts are.  For example...

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Only the real parts of wavefunctions have physical significance. The complex part is included so that the wavefunction can be expressed as an exponential using Euler's relation. Exponentials are easier to handle mathematically than trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics and quantum field theory, both the real and imaginary parts of a complex quantity are physically significant. (This is because the complex quantities are used to predict real observables as eigenvalues.) However, it is often more helpful to seek physical interpretations of the modulus and phase instead, just as polar coordinates are a better description than Cartesian ones for a planar orbit due to a radial force. For example, squared moduli in quantum mechanics give probability amplitudes, and moduli in theories with $U(N)$ or $SU(N)$ symmetries can have observable interpretations. (For example, masses due to the Higgs field are proportional to such moduli.)